# Getting return undefined on recursive function javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I heard recursive function is powerful so instead going through loop i tried to create a function which increments a number until it reach certain points. when it reaches i tried to return the value, but it give `undefined`.

CODE

```
var i=1;
function rec(){
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    if(i > 100){
        return i;
    }else{
        rec();
    }
}

console.log(rec());
```

Here the `i` is incrementing until 100. but it returns undefined after the limit. Why is this happening? Also please let me know, it this kind of recursion is good then `for` loop?

Comment: `else { return rec(); }` ?

Comment: no. after it become > 100 i need to return. until i will call the function to increment the number. Just to practice recursion.

Comment: @rram: **Yes**, vaultah is right. Why don't you just try it? And step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Dang! Now I know what it feels like..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088739/getting-return-undefined-on-recursive-function-javascript/27088772#comment42684996_27088739) by [vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) is correct:

```js
var i=1;
function rec(){
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    if(i > 100){
        return i;
    }else{
        return rec();
    }
}

snippet.log(rec());
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Let's take an example that only counts to `> 5` and add some output so you can see what happens more easily (but again, stepping through the code with a debugger is the right way to see how this works):

```js
var indent = "";
var i=1;
function rec(){
    var rv;
    i++;
    indent += "&nbsp;";
    if(i > 5){
      snippet.logHTML("<p>" + indent + i + " > 5, returning " + i + "</p>");
        rv = i;
    }else{
        snippet.logHTML("<p>" + indent + i + " is not > 5, calling rec</p>");
        rv = rec();
        snippet.logHTML("<p>" + indent + "Got " + rv + " back from rec, returning it</p>");
    }
    indent = indent.substring(0, indent.length - 6);
    return rv;
}

snippet.logHTML("<p>Final result: " + rec() + "</p>");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: Thanks for you guide. +1. Please check my latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL035h8h/).i got the idea of recursion. but why it didn't stop when i become 101 and just return 101. Instead it is returning undefined.

Comment: @rram: Because ***again*** the call that you're printing the result of doesn't return anything. If you step through the code, it'll become obvious why the above is how you do this.

Comment: What do you mean by step through code? Right now i am seeing the logs in firebug console. Here is the one more updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL035h8h/1/). Please check my comment too

Comment: @rram: A debugger can let you stop your code and then execute each line one at a time, looking at variables and such while you'er doing it. That's called "stepping through the code in a debugger." Meanwhile, see the second snippet above.

Comment: Sorry now more confused. Why are we getting `Got 6 back from rec, returning it` 4 times in the else part

Comment: @rram: Right. That's how recursive functions like this work. Each call calls the next until you reach your termination condition, then that final result bubbles up through all the outstanding calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65465/discussion-between-rram-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: This is how the output should be, isn't? `2 is not > 5, calling rec
    Got 2 back from rec, returning it
  3 is not > 5, calling rec
    Got 3 back from rec, returning it
   4 is not > 5, calling rec
    Got 4 back from rec, returning it
    5 is not > 5, calling rec
    Got 5 back from rec, returning it
     6 > 5, returning 6


Final result: 6`

Comment: @rram: No, the output should be what it is above. Find out how to use the debugger built into your browser (instructions will be on the browser's website), we can't help you any further here. The above is how you do this. The reason you're seeing undefined is that you're not returning the result of calling `rec`, as several people have now told you.

Comment: OK sorry. I'll try to check in debugger. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`rec` will either return `i` (if `i` is over 100) or `undefined` (otherwise).

When you call it here:

```
console.log(rec());
```

`i` will be `1` so it will return `undefined`.

You never do anything with the return value when the return value is over 100.

You need to return the result of the recursive call:

```
} else {
    return rec();
}
```

so when it is over 100, the value gets passed back up the stack.

> it this kind of recursion is good then for loop?

No. It is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help in explaining, but i couldn't understand a bit. Here is my doubt. I'm trying to increment the `i` variable until it becomes > 100. that is 101. so if that satisfies then i'm returning the `i` so the function stops. So no more recursion happen. The idea of return is to stop the recursion. instead why it is giving undefined at last? Here is the [fiddle of modified code](http://jsfiddle.net/wL035h8h/) Please advice

Comment: @rram: Again, step through the code in a debugger (there's one built into your browser). The first call to `rec` will increment `i` and then check it. Since `2` is not `> 100`, we go to the `else`. In the `else`, we do `return rec()` which **calls `rec`**. This second call to `rec` increments `i` again, sees that `3` is not `> 100`, and calls `rec` again. This is the point of a recursive algorithm. Eventually, the 99th call to `rec` sees `i > 100` and returns `i`, which allows the 98th call to return (and it returns the same value), which allows the 97th call to return, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with explanation of whether this is better than for loop. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just use the return statement and you can check the code in the console like

```
var i=1;
function rec(){
i++;
console.log(i);
if(i > 100){
    return i;
}else{
    return rec();
}
}

console.log(rec());
```

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the following code after your function ends:

```
typeof rec === 'undefined'
```